# Docker volume not getting deleted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an application where I need to reset the database (wipe it completely).

I ran all the commands I could find

```bash
docker system prune
docker system prune -a -f
docker volume prune
```

Using `docker volume ls`, I copied the volume ID and then ran

```bash
docker volume rm "the volume id"
```

When I do `docker system df` nothing is shown anymore. However, once I run my app again

```bash
docker-compose up --build
```

the database still contains old values.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nftapi:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres

    networks:
      - postgres

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    
    restart: always

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
  pgadmin:
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Did you delete the container entirely ? If you do docker volume prune, all unused volumes should disappear..

Comment: yes, I ran all commands system prune, volume prune -a - f flags so docker volume ls shows nothing anymore, docker system dfshows nothing anymore. But whenever I run docker-compose up --build the database contains old values still

Comment: What's in the `docker-compose.yml` file; where is the database data stored?  (If you're bind-mounting a host directory, `docker volume` operations won't affect it.)

Comment: what returns `docker container ls -a` ? I don't think it should be necessary but you can also try to delete the image. Then run system prune and volume prune..

Comment: I edited original post to include my compose file. Maybe that gives someone with a better understanding of docker than myself a hint

Answer (score 3):

It seems the database in your config is mapped to a directory on your host system:

```
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

so the data in the containers `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is read from and written to your local `/data/postgres` directory.

If you want to delete it you should empty out that directory. (Or move it until you are sure that you can delete it)

Comment: Oh thats probably it. I was assuming (wrongly) that the docker commands also effect the mapped volumes as form my understanding, the reason for volumes is to be persisted and mapped to the local machines. Thank you I will try that

Answer (score -1):

Use `docker volume ls -q` to list volumes then `docker volume rm` to remove.

Or combine both steps:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it